# .NET ETW - Manifest file not generated

Tags: .net-4.5, etw

doing logging component using .NET 4.5
working to log into event log, using ETW

4.5 did include ETW framework into System.Diagnostic.Tracing.*
however samples and external project lead to install **Microsft**.Diagnostic.Tracing.*
it's really confusing. But for testing purposes, I'm sticking to Microsoft.*

RegisterEvent tool is installed, and attached to the class library containing the custom EventSource, build is good, but I can't see the manifest file (.man) being generated

I'm lost. afaik, I need that .man for manual registration, only then event log will spew out my magic

Answer (score 0):

my custom EventSource is named exactly "EventSource", need to rename to something else like "OMGEventSource"

while trying to fix the initial issue, I switched to using System.Diagnostic.Tracing
however, it's Event class doesn't have Channel property, which is needed by the RegisterEvent tool to generate the man file
have to switch back to use Microsoft.*

in short, forget about System.Diagnostic.Tracing, just stick to Microsoft.*